# Unable to push code to Google Cloud Repository

Tags: git, gcloud

I am new to GCloud, trying to setup the git repository. I am unable to push code thru git. 
I followed the steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes). I went thru other questions posted on stackoverflow and google.

I keep getting this error:

```
git push google master

ERROR: (gcloud.auth.git-helper) Invalid input line format: [path=].
fatal: remote error: Invalid username/password.
You may need to use your OAuth token password; Note that generated google.com passwords are not compatible with
repositories
```

I ran gcloud init at the start. Why am I getting the Path and OAuth token error? Where should I enter this information?

Comment: What version of git and what OS are you using?

Comment: @cherba I solved it. Apparently, gcloud uses the different gitconfig file for AllUsers and Single User installation configuration. Updated the Program Files gitconfig as AppData. It started working